# Shifting a tilemap in the opposite direction of a mouse click with HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, math, canvas, vector

I have a .png map file that I would like to respond to player mouse clicks. To simulate the player moving in the direction of the mouse click, I believe the map should shift in the opposite direction of the click, by a distance of the resulting length vector between the mouse click and current center position of the map. Is this the correct intuition? I can get this to work perfectly by moving the map around with the keyboard, but I really would like to use the mouse to control the player, similar to that of Diablo II and RuneScape.

Right now, I can get my map to shift it's origin along a smooth path until it hits the mouse click position, but it appears visually to shift in the wrong direction (it's shifting correctly, towards the mouse, but for the player, it should shift the opposite direction). Simply multiplying by -1 doesn't work correctly and I think I'm missing some fundamental equation to make this work. Here is my code for the map shift so far:

Here is the relevant code:
Main file:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 960;
canvas.height = 640;

class Sprite {
  constructor(imgPath) {
    console.log(imgPath);
    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.src = imgPath;

    this.position = {
      x: 0 - canvas.width / 2,
      y: 0 - canvas.height / 2,
    };
  }
}

class PlayerCharacter {
  constructor() {
    this.sprite = new Image();
    this.sprite.src = "/assets/pixelface.png";
    this.x = canvas.width / 2 - 40;
    this.y = canvas.height / 2 - 40;
    this.speed = 2;
    this.xMove = 0;
    this.yMove = 0;
    this.moveTo = null;
  }

  checkUserInput(map) {
    if (this.moveTo) {
      let centerOffsetMapPos = {
        x: map.position.x + canvas.width / 2,
        y: map.position.y + canvas.height / 2,
      };
      let targetDirection = Vector2.direction(centerOffsetMapPos, this.moveTo);
      let vectorLength = targetDirection.length();
      console.log(vectorLength);
      if (vectorLength > this.speed) {
        let normalizedVector = targetDirection.normalize();
        this.xMove = normalizedVector.x * this.speed;
        this.yMove = normalizedVector.y * this.speed;
      } else {
        this.xMove = 0;
        this.yMove = 0;
        this.moveTo = null;
      }
    }
  }
}

const playerCharacter = new PlayerCharacter();
const map = new Sprite("/assets/apocdemo2.png");

canvas.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  playerCharacter.moveTo = {
    x: e.offsetX,
    y: e.offsetY,
  };
});

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(map.image, map.position.x, map.position.y);

  ctx.drawImage(
    playerCharacter.sprite,
    playerCharacter.x,
    playerCharacter.y,
    80,
    80
  );

  playerCharacter.checkUserInput(map);
  map.position.x += playerCharacter.xMove;
  map.position.y += playerCharacter.yMove;
  if (map.position.y + map.image.height <= canvas.height) {
    map.position.y = (map.image.height - canvas.height) * -1;
  }
}

function run() {
  draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(run);
}

run();
```

My Vector2 utility class:

```
class Vector2 {
  static direction(current, target) {
    return new Vector2(target.x - current.x, target.y - current.y);
  }
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  length() {
    return Math.sqrt(this.x ** 2 + this.y ** 2);
  }

  multiply(val) {
    this.x * val;
    this.y * val;
  }

  normalize() {
    let mag = this.length();
    let x = this.x / mag;
    let y = this.y / mag;
    return new Vector2(x, y);
  }
}
```

I suspect I am doing something wrong with the offsets on the map or how I am multiplying the vectors.